# What is the context of an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, this, anonymous-function

I have code like this:

```
function demo() {
    this.val=5;
    function() {
        this.val=7;
    }();
}
```

Now when I give execute this code in the firefox or chrome console it gives a syntax error. I don't understand why this is an error because I have read that javascript functions are objects so when I call the anonymous function, inside it `this` points to function demo and should change the `val` to `7`, so if I do

```
var x=new demo();
x.val;   //should give 7
```

but when I do this

```
function demo() {
    this.val=5;
    var f=function() {
            this.val=7;
    }();
}
window.val;    // gives 7
```

I don't understand if functions are objects then why the `this` in the anonymous function points to `window` and not `demo`. 
Please explain this.

Comment: That's just the way it works. If you call a function "normally", the `this` keyword will point to the global object...

Comment: @Šime Vidas what is "normally" here? and are functions not objects?

Comment: "normally" = by appending parens to the name of the function, for instance: `foo()`. The other ways of calling a function are (1) like a constructor and (2) via `call`/`apply`. In those cases, the rules for the `this` keyword are different. Yes, functions are objects.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> i dont understand why this is an error

because

```
function() {
    this.val=7;
}();
```

is evaluated as function **declaration** and function declarations need a name. To make it interpreted as function **expression**, you need to put it in parenthesis:

```
 (function() {
    this.val=7;
 }());
```

(making it an immediate function)

or assign  the function to a variable:

```
var f = function() {....};
f();
```

What you do in the second snippet is a mixture of both and although being valid, it does not make much sense. `f` will have the value `undefined`.

> i dont understand if functions are objects then why the this in the anonymous function points to `window` and not `demo`.

Functions don't inherit the context they are called in. Every function has it's own `this` and what `this` refers to is determined by *how* the function is called. It basically boils down to:

- "Standalone" ( `func()`) or as immediate function ( `(function(){...}())` ) : `this` will refer to the global object (`window` in browsers)
- As property of an object ( `obj.func()`): `this` will refer to `obj`
- With the [`new` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/new) keyword ( `new Func()` ): `this` refers to an empty object that inherits from `Func.prototype`
- [`apply` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) and [`call` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call) methods ( `func.apply(someObj)` ): `this` refers to `someObj`

---

Further reading:

- [MDC JavaScript Guide - Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [MDC JavaScript Reference - Function and functions scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)
- [ECMAScript 5, Section 13 - Function Definition](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13)

Comment: I could be wrong but I think your parentheses are slightly off on `(function() {
    this.val=7;
 }());`  doesn't the `()` come after the closing `)`?

Comment: @Felix Kling what does a function's `this` points to? can u please elaborate?

Comment: @kingjiv: That does not matter actually. But JSLint prefers the "calling" parenthesis inside.

Comment: @lovesh: I thought I have provided enough information. As I said, it depends on how the function is called. What is unclear?

Comment: Good to know.  Guess I just assumed having usually seen it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you described like this:

```
function demo() {
    var self=this;

    this.val = 5;

    var f = (function() {
        self.val = 7;
    })();
}
```

Comment: i understand that if i want ot change val i can do this but my whole poiny is that if functions are objects then why doesnt `this` points to a function, in my case(`demo`)

Comment: @king This code is misleading. The inner function is an IIFE, so the value which is assigned to the variable `f` is `undefined`, not the function object itself. IIFE's should be wrapped in parens.

Comment: It is just an object defined inside that function, it's not really a part of the object you create when you call `new demo()`.  If you were to change it to `this.f = function()` and then call `this.f()` it would then be called with `this` being the object.

Comment: @lovesh Why would the fact that functions are objects lead to the conclusion that `this` points to the functions itself? Those two things are unrelated...

Comment: @Šime fair enough, i always wrap it but had just taken it from his code.  I think I was misunderstanding his misunderstanding anyway, so I don't think this is helpful either way.

Comment: @love Well, it doesn't. Why do you think it should?

Comment: @Šime Vidas i m sorry i was mistaken. probably i should crash now its been a long day and i am acting stupid

Comment: @love Well, if you're in India, then you should definitively go to sleep now (since it's 4AM at your place) `:)`.