# Referencing Object Properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

If I have The code:

```
function RandomObjectThatIsntNamedObjectWhichIOriginallyNamedObjectOnAccident() {
    this.foo = 0;
    this.bar = function () {
        this.naba = function () {
            //How do I reference foo here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, Object is a terrible function name. You can override javascript's Object

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do with `naba`. How are you calling it? What are you doing with `Object`? What `this` refers to eventually depends on *how* you are calling the functions. As long as we don't know this, we can only guess what would be the best solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a `self` reference:

```
function RandomObjectThatIsntNamedObjectWhichIOriginallyNamedObjectOnAccident() {
    var self = this;
    this.foo = 0;
    this.bar = function () {
        this.naba = function () {
            self.foo; //foo!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about using that, but was concerned that it might actually create a copy of the object instead of just creating a reference. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Of course, you could never create an "Object" since it overrides `Object`

Comment: @ConnerRuhl -- no problem ^_^

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory -- I know that, i was just going off the OP's post. did not really think abt the object's name.

Answer (score 6):

```
function SomeObject() {
    var self = this;
    this.foo = 0;
    this.bar = function () {
        this.naba = function () {
            self.foo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `+1` for getting in 2 seconds after me ^_^

Comment: I blame the captchas, I would have been 20 seconds earlier ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
function SomeObject() {
    var self = this;
    this.foo = 0;
    this.bar = function () {
        this.naba = function () {
            //How do I reference foo here?
            self.foo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really use `var self`, because `this.self` will make `self` publicly accessible.

Comment: @Rocket, well, no, it will just have the same issue as before... where you cannot access it, i do not see how this works.

Comment: @JaredPar -- good fix, and it makes me all warm and fuzzy inside that users with >150K rep can still make mistakes :-P

Comment: @Neal I make tons of mistakes, especially if I post before I finish the morning coffee :)

Answer (score 1):

First: Don't name your function `Object`, it will shadow the global `Object` constructor.

I don't see a reason why you have to assign `naba` inside `bar` to the instance. Why are you doing this? You can assign both `bar` and `naba` to the functions prototype:

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.foo = 0;
}

MyConstructor.prototype.bar = function () {

};

MyConstructor.prototype.naba = function () {
    // this.foo
};
```

Eventually it  depends on *how* you are calling the `naba` function. The fact that you are assigning it  to `this` suggests you want to call it with

```
var obj = new MyConstructor();
obj.naba();
```

If you want to add `naba` only after `bar` was called, you can still access `foo` via `this.foo`:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.bar = function () {
    if(!this.naba) {
        this.naba = function() {
            // this.foo
        };
    }
};

var obj = new MyConstructor();
obj.bar();
obj.naba();
```

If you want a proper/better answer, you have to show how you are going to use `naba`.

Comment: What you're suggesting is not equivalent. `naba` gets assigned to `bar`, not the object. I general I would suggest you don't use `this` or `prototype` at all because it's very error prone. Most people seem to completely misunderstand how JavaScript works (and that it works without prototype). If you'd like I could post an equivalent solution that doesn't use `this` or `prototype`.

Comment: @Frits: I think I understand how it works. `naba` never gets assigned to `bar`, it gets assigned to whatever `this` refers to. Most likely it is an instance of the constructor function, but it could as well be `window`. But `this` is *never* `bar`. And if you have a constructor function, then using a prototype is the preferred way to attach instance methods (saves memory). And I don't see what is error prone with `this` or prototype. It might be difficult to understand at first, but there is nothing overall mystical about it.

Comment: It seems you are correct, and it's exactly what I mean, `this` is confusing. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ7c2/

Comment: @Fritz: What `this` refers to depends on *how* the function is called. There are four different ways, [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796521/what-is-the-context-of-an-anonymous-function/6796627#6796627). Which means that in order to give a proper answer, we would have to know how the OP is calling all these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, you don't need to do anything special.

The `this` reference works:

```
function SomeObject() {
  this.foo = 0;
  this.bar = function () {
    this.naba = function () {
      alert(this.foo); // this works!
    }
  }
}
```

Since you're assigning "methods" always to the same reference, `this` will still point to it inside `bar`, and later inside `naba`.

Comment: That is when you `Object` is a function and **NOT** an object. try it with `new`. then it does not work.

Comment: I think this is what you meant to show: http://jsfiddle.net/t2Qha/1/ (which suprisingly works)

Comment: @Neal: When you call `var obj = new Object(); obj.bar(); obj.naba();` then it will work, because `this` always references `obj`.

Comment: @Neal: Come on, there have been like 25 seconds between our comments. Do you inspect me to refresh the page every 10 seconds? ;)

Comment: @Neal: yes, your example is better, but the code in the answer is still the same... thanks.

Comment: This breaks down if you call `naba` through another object.  For example `var y = {}; y.naba = obj.naba; y.naba();`

Comment: @JaredPar: that's kind of cheating.... I wouldn't expect to be able to cover that scenario on any _sane_ project.

Comment: @JaredPar: As do most instance methods, e.g. `var y = {}; y.getElementById = document.getElementById;`. We don't know how the OP is calling the methods or what he wants to do with them.

Comment: @Jordão the `var self = this;` solution does fix this problem.  I don't think this is cheating though as it's how event handlers run in Javascript.

Comment: @JaredPar: That's a totally different use case. Btw `y.naba = obj.naba.bind(obj);` "fixes" your "problem" too.

Comment: @JaredPar: It's cheating because I can sabotage any "method" in any "class" that accesses `this` by assigning the "method" to another object that doesn't provide the accessed members. That invalidates the use of `this` outside _any_ constructors.

Comment: Oh, it's not capturing the self reference that's cheating, it's assigning the function to another object....

Comment: @Jordão it doesn't necessarily need to be assigned to get a different context. Another way is to use `apply`.  Example: `obj.nada.apply({})`.  I agree these are bordering on corner cases but they can be relevant when working with call back APIs.

Comment: @JaredPar: it could be argued that the _intent_ of running a function in a different context is to use `foo` from _that_ context, which the self reference solution doesn't allow.